# jQuery get height of first 3 li tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I am filling a unordered list with dynamic content and the list height will fir the content, does anyone know how I can get the height of the first 3 li tags in the unordered list?

The dynamic content produced might be something like below so I just want to be able to calculate the height of the first 3 li tags.

```
<ul>
<li>23 Feb 2011<br />Synergy Launch new website...<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc gravida lacus a ligula dictum dignissim....</li>
<li>23 Feb 2011<br />Expat children "receive improv...<br />Expat children enjoy a better standard of education whilst living abroad compared to their home country according to the HSBC Offshore Offspring Report,...</li>
<li>25 Feb 2011<br />London Market favours Landlord...<br />The lettings market has swung dramatically in favour of landlords as an average six applicants chase every available property in London. This is a dramatic rise...</li>
<li>23 Feb 2011<br />Synergy Launch new website...<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc gravida lacus a ligula dictum dignissim....</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for any help
J.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This provides you with all of their height... but you could easily just put the code you want inside the function to perform something on each list item.

```
var sum = 0;

$('li:lt(3)').each(function() {
   sum += $(this).height();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rnpAE/1/

**EDIT:** Shortened`$('li').nextUntil(':eq(2)')` to `$('li:lt(3)')`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to calculate them individually use the eq selector

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

```
var liHeight = $('li:eq(0)').outerHeight(); // Obtains height of first li
```

Comment: `eq()` is zero-based, so the code in your answer actually obtains the height of the *second* list item.

Answer (score 1):

First I set a var to be minus 1 item...

```
var liTotalHeight = -24;
```

Then, for each item, I add the height of the li ..

```
liTotalHeight = liTotalHeight + $(this).outerHeight();
```

Then I set the ul's scrollTop ...

```
$(this).parent().scrollTop(liTotalHeight);
```

A little hacky, but works best for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').height(); // First
$('li').next().height(); // Second
$('li').next().next().height(); // Third
```

Or use [`outerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) if you want to include padding/margin.